# Scraping a website with Html Agility Pack. Response of GET not as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

Using System.Net.HttpRequest I would like to imitate a users search on the following search engine in my code.

http://www.scirus.com

An example of the search URL is as follows:

http://www.scirus.com/srsapp/search?q=core+facilities&t=all&sort=0&g=s

I have the following code to perform the HTTP GET. Note I'm using the HtmlAgilityPack.

```
protected override HtmlDocument MakeRequestHtml(string requestUrl)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
        return (htmlDoc);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.Read();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Where "requestUrl" is the example search URL shown above.

The contents of htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml contains no search results and looks nothing like the search results page you would get if you copy pasted the example search URL shown above into your browser.

I'm guessing the reason for this is because you must first have a session in order to be able to perform requests. Can anybody advise if there is a feasible way to replicate the behavior of the user agent? Or perhaps there is a better way of achieving the goal of "scraping" the search results that I don't know about? Suggestions please.

Robots.txt contents:

```
# / robots.txt file for http://www.scirus.com

User-agent: NetMechanic
Disallow: /srsapp/sciruslink

User-agent: *
Disallow: /srsapp/sciruslink
Disallow: /srsapp/search
Disallow: /srsapp/search_simple
Disallow: /search_simple
# for dev and accept server uncomment below line at Build time to disallow robots completely
##Disallow: /
```

Content of htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml

[image: Response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I actually tested with webclient

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0");
        string str = client.DownloadString("http://www.scirus.com/srsapp/search?q=core+facilities&t=all&sort=0&g=s"); 
        byte[] bit = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(str);
        FileStream fil = File.OpenWrite("test.txt");
        fil.Write(bit,0,bit.Length);
    }
```

And here is the downloaded file http://pastebin.com/qswtgC4n

Comment: Thanks that works. Actually the original code works as well. The problem was caused by incorrect formatting of the requestUrl parameter for the MakeRequestHtml method.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to set a user agent, e.g.

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
```

You should also check the site's Robots.txt file to make sure you are welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still get the same entirely different HTML in the response produced via the code to that produced via the browser. I have posted the updated code including the robots.txt. Do you have any further recommendations?

Comment: Thanks for testing it. I've updated the post to show the response I get from the request. It's not the same as opening this link in the browser http://www.scirus.com/srsapp/search?q=core+facilities&t=all&sort=0&g=s . Can you confirm that you're getting the same HTML running the code as you are by opening the link above in the browser and if you are getting the same HTML what might I be doing wrong to get the incorrect HTML I'm receiving at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are not pinging the server excessively, especially if the code to load the document was previously working.  You may have run into a server rule that is sending you to the robots.txt or similar page.